# Wifi packet loss problem with Mac

Tags: network, wifi

(MacBook pro 16" 2019 big sur [latest])

I have a problem with my wifi. I noticed that my browser gets "stuck" by not loading pages, or taking too long doing that (any browser).

I tested this using the command in the terminal: `ping 8.8.8.8` and noticed that it misses packets every once in a while and then gets back to normal. sometimes this happens with big chunks of packets, and sometimes with 1-4.

[image]

I tested this on my android phone which is located right next to my macbook and connected to the same wifi network with a 100% success.

Can you please help me resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you used `ping` on another device in the house connected to the wifi? This kind of pattern could be caused by interference

Comment: set the [DNS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh14127/mac) to something like 1.1.1.2 and the [MTU to 1453](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2505/mac) on your Mac. Are your Mac and the phone on the same band (2.4 or 5 Ghz) connected to your router?

Answer (score 0):

maybe is an hardware issue with the wifi card.

do you have an external usb wifi to make the test?
if yes then connect it and run the same ping command and see what happens.

Also you can check if drivers are correctly installed for the wifi card. :)